# Excel VBA: Worksheet_Change method not working inside my Module

Tags: vba, excel

In my module I added a method.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print "H"
End Sub
```

I have two tables in that sheet. I try to enter values inside one table but this subroutine is not getting executed.  What is wrong here?

I have a table, where I need to allow entering a value inside a cell only if another cell of the same row have a particular value? Is there a better way to do that?

[image]

Thanks
Jeevan

Comment: Check if events are enabled for that to work or you can do it by `Application.EnableEvents = True`. Did you check the `Immediate Window` whether it works or not ?

Comment: You have added it to a worksheet module and not a normal or class module?

Comment: Yes I checked Immediate Window. I never made Application.EnableEvents = False anywhere. I added it in normal module, which comes under the hierarchy "Modules".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Put it inside the sheet module and not the module module

[image]

Just additional info, in the sheet module you can find the list of EventListerners available from the drop down menu too. These are not available in a module module.

[image]

Comment: How can I add an Event for a particular module alone?

Comment: @Jeevan you can create the EventListener in a sheet module to call a procedure in a module module.

Comment: I shall search for EventListener and try to figure out how to do that. Thanks.